# Multiple virtual inheritance from a single class in c++

Tags: c++, oop, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance, diamond-problem

The following code raises an ambiguity between `Horse::getcolour()` and `Bird::getcolour()` which is totally unanticipated as the classes `Bird` and `Horse` are virtually inherited by the class `Pegasus` which must have avoided this error.

```
class Animal {
    public:
        Animal(int itsAge):age(itsAge) { cout << "Animal Constructor.\n"; }
        virtual ~Animal() { cout << "Animal Destructor.\n"; }
        int GetAge() const { return age; }
        void SetAge(int itsAge) { age=itsAge; }
    private:
        int age;
};
class Bird: virtual public Animal {
    public:
        Bird(string colour,int itsAge);
        virtual ~Bird() { cout << "Bird Destructor.\n"; }
        void Fly() const { cout << "Flying!!!!\n"; }
        virtual void Chirp() const { cout << "Chirpppp!!!!\n"; }
        virtual string getcolour() const { return colour; }
    protected:
        string colour;
};
Bird::Bird(string colour,int itsAge):colour(colour),Animal(itsAge) { 
    cout << "Bird Constructor.\n";
}
class Horse: virtual public Animal {
    public:
        Horse(string colour,int itsAge);
        virtual ~Horse() { cout << "Horse Destructor.\n"; }
        virtual void Whine() const { cout << "Whinnnnne!!!\n"; }
        virtual string getcolour() const { return colour; }
    protected:
        string colour;
};
Horse::Horse(string colour,int itsAge):colour(colour),Animal(itsAge) { 
    cout << "Horse Constructor.\n";
}
class Pegasus:virtual public Horse,virtual public Bird { // inherits both Horse and Bird virtually
    public:
        Pegasus(string colour,int n,int itsAge);
        ~Pegasus() { cout << "Pegasus Destructor.\n"; }
        void Chirp() const { Horse::Whine(); }
    private:
        int nBelievers;
};
Pegasus::Pegasus(string colour,int n,int itsAge):Animal(itsAge),Horse(colour,itsAge),Bird(colour,itsAge),nBelievers(n) { 
    cout << "Pegasus Constructor.\n"; 
}
int main() {
    Pegasus *p=new Pegasus("Black",44,4);
    cout << "Colour of this pegasus: " << p->getcolour(); // Error is thrown
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone point out the fault in the code above and suggest me the correct logic/syntax if I am wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Both `Bird` and `Horse` have `colour` fields and corresponding getters so could you not just make `colour` a `protected` field of the base `Animal`?

Comment: As you really have two distinct versions of `getcolour()` it must be specified directly: `p->Horse::getcolour()`.

Comment: Note that your `pegasus` is currently of two colours.

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury That solution may fix the problem at hand logically but generally we do not specify the colour of an organism in real life as it is a bit vague; like we do not say 'this animal is red', we usually say 'this bird is red'. Do you have any more solutions?? Thanks for response.

Comment: That's true but the English language is imprecise and can be rather ambiguous - something that programming languages can't afford. In this case, every `Animal` has a `colour` so I'd say it makes sense to declare `colour` in the base class to avoid repetition.

Comment: `we do not say 'this animal is red', we usually say 'this bird is red'` Actually your problem is due to the fact that pegasus is neither bird nor horse. So you shouldn't derive it from these ones.

Comment: @Matt That solution of using the scope resolution operator (::) solves all the problems in the infamous 'diamond problem' without the use of virtual inheritance. So that cannot be considered as a recommended solution. Isn't there any way to solve it without using the scope resolution operator ?

Comment: `Isn't there any way to solve it without using the scope resolution operator ?` Redo your inheritance tree completely. It's bad idea to think pegasus as "horse and bird".

Comment: @Matt Mind suggesting me one? The way how you would solve this problem using virtual inheritance and minimizing the use of scope resolution operators i.e only using them when no other solution is possible.

Comment: So guys does this mean that there is no way to solve this ambiguity without the use of scope resolution operator ? I feel that since the same colour is assigned to the 'colour' property of both horse and bird by the pegasus constructor, there must be a solution to this via virtual inheritance itself.

Comment: `solve this problem using virtual inheritance` Why VI at all? At least in this particular setup I see no use of it. Pegasus is just "FantasyAnymal", no VI.

Comment: `no way to solve this ambiguity` That's a true ambiguity as your pegasus has two colours. You've made it like this, so do not expect the compiler to fix it.

Comment: So there is no way to solve it, right? Does that means I either need to create a new class named 'Pegasus' itself and declare all methods and properties in it without inheritance or follow the advice given by @ArchbishopOfBanterbury i.e. to declare colour property in the animal class ? Thanks to all of you guys for your help.

Comment: How about instead of a Bird class, have a ThingThatCanFly class, with only a virtual void Fly() method in it ?  (That would make more sense, since a Pegasus is definitely not a bird, and doesn't ever chirp AFAIK :))   [ThingThatCanFly would have no superclass, and Pegasus would non-virtually derive from both Animal and ThingThatCanFly]

Comment: You can always introduce a further level of indirection by adding a ColorfulAnimal class... Both Bird and Horse can derive from it (virtually), then you do the rest as you'd normally do.